# how to properly use wildcard on a elastic search find?

Tags: elasticsearch

I just jumped into ES and I dont have a lot of experience on this, so might be something I am missing on this.

I found this documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html that basically explains how to do a wildcard search.

I am trying to look for all messages inside my document that have certain patter.

So, using Kibana Sense (Elastic search query UI)I did this:

```
GET _search
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard" : {
            "model.message": "my*"
        }
    }
}
```

with this I am trying to obtain all the messages that start with **"my"**

But I get no results...

Here is a copy of my document structure (or at least the first lines...)

```
 "_index": "my_index",
    "_type": "my_type",
    "_id": "123456",
    "_source": {
      "model": {
        "id": "123456",
        "message": "my message",
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sample document actually contains the `model.content.message` field but not the `model.message` field, so the following query should work:

```
GET _search
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard" : {
            "model.content.message": "my*"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my bad, message is not inside content, I didnt close the {}, still I run the query just with model.message, should it work that way?

Comment: Can you show the mapping of your index? `GET my_index`

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your mapping? It looks like you need to use a nested query:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "model",
            "score_mode" : "avg",
            "query" : {
                "wildcard" : {
                    "model.message": "my*"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more about nested queries [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html).

Comment: how can I get the mapping?

Comment: `GET my_index/my_type/_mapping`. Did you try using the nested query? I believe that will fix your query, I just wanted the mapping to verify.

Comment: but this query doesnt work, get me a query_shard_exception :s

Comment: You need to provide the mapping so we know how your documents are structured.